# How to send data from external device to OS with rs232 and fake it as a mouse

Tags: uart, rs232, mouse

I have a project that i need to send some data with an RS232 to USB cable from external Msp430 launchpad to the computer and fake it as a mouse. Is this possible without learning USB protocols of the mouse?

Comment: That is a good question. The original mice [were using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_mouse#Serial_interface_and_protocol) a [COM port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_%28hardware_interface%29), so why not? It ***seems*** to [be possible under Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/4/mouse).

Comment: That is, PC mice.

Answer (score 1):

You could pretend to be a Microsoft Serial Mouse:
http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/serialmouse/

Edit: if that doesn't work, and the computer has a PS/2 mouse port, you can use that: http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2protocol/

Otherwise you're going to have to get a microcontroller with USB support and learn that, which will be time-consuming.

Comment: Does that still work with newer OSes? I remember I tried using some serial mice with Vista and 7 and they didn't work, but I didn't try to figure out if they died or the OS didn't support them.

Comment: Hmm - it's not clear, although I can see a couple of questions on stackexchange about "how do I prevent my serial device being wrongly detected as a mouse on Win7?".

Comment: This is basically the answer.  I'd just point out that a USB HID implementation may not be all that complicated if you find a microcontroller eval board with an HID mouse demo.  Some of these will cost less than a logic-level USB-serial cable.

Comment: Both links are broken.

Comment: For the ***second*** link (the whole www.computer-engineering.org site is broken (the domain expired)): Some alternatives are (essentially the ***same content by the same author***, but slightly different titles and modification dates): *[The PS/2 Mouse/Keyboard Protocol](https://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/PS2%20Keyboard.pdf)* (2003-05-09), *[The PS/2 Keyboard Interface](http://www-ug.eecg.toronto.edu/msl/nios_devices/datasheets/PS2%20Keyboard%20Protocol.htm)* (2003-04-01), and *[The AT-PS/2 Keyboard Interface](https://www.tayloredge.com/reference/Interface/atkeyboard.pdf)* (2001).

Answer (score 0):

Microchip has a [PICDEM Full Speed USB Demo Board](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en021940) for this. This demo board comes with a program that emmulates a HID mouse using USB. You could adapt this program to create your fake mouse.